# Getting the Android version makes every Bluetooth device disconnect

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, version

If I have a Bluetooth device connected to my device, when I try to get the Android version, either with

```
Platform.operatingSystemVersion;
```

Or using the [device_info_plus package](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus), every device gets disconnected... I know it sounds strange, but if I comment that line of code, the device remains connected...

Does anyone know why? Or is there another method to retrieve the Android version?

Comment: Are any other functions working? It might be that it remains connected because no data is attempted to transfer. Usually those kinds of things only "know" if you are connected or disconnected when you attempt to send data to the other side.

Comment: Yes the rest is working perfectly fine, and if I keep that "get the Android version" function commented, everything else keeps working fine, including the Bluetooth device that works as it should... But if I use that function, the device gets disconnected before I even have the chance to test the device or use it

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that this function might causing the Bluetooth device to crash and that's why its behaving like that.